# Dismiss two instances of ViewCntroller separately Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I have a tabbed bar app with two tabs. Where VC 2 can segue directly to VC 1

[image]

This works fine but the problem arises when I do this

1. Open VC 2 (Tab 2)
2. Segue to VC 1 from VC 2 (presenting modally
   and without switching the tab)
3. Switch to Tab 1 (VC 1)
4. Switch to Tab 2 and dismiss modally presented VC 1

When I dismiss VC 1 (on Tab 2) after switching from VC 1 (Tab 1), black screen appears.

Do I need to dismiss one instance before switching to another instance of same ViewController?

Comment: Share some code

Comment: You should dismiss `UINavigationController` of vc1 but not vc1. If you only dismiss vc1, there is black `UINavigationController` displaying.

Comment: @Codus thanks for suggestion. I tried with both "dismiss" and "pop" for UINavigationContgroller instead of vc1 but it doesn't work.

Comment: How did you dismiss modally presented VC 1? share some code.

Comment: @Codus In VC1 I do `@IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }`

Comment: Show your code how you are present view controller ?

Comment: @MikeAlter in `prepareForSegue` of VC2 I do, `let DestViewController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let destinationVC = DestViewController.topViewController as! VC1`

Comment: You are presenting `DestViewController`  or `destinationVC`

Comment: @MikeAlter `destinationVC`

Comment: try to present`  DestViewController` and dismiss with `self.dismiss`

Comment: How are you switching to Tab 1 when VC1 is presented modally in Tab 2? It is covering full device screen i.e. tab bar not even visible.

Comment: @PGDev I am presenting VC1 through NavigationVC, from VC2

Answer (score 0):

You need to dismiss modally presented controllers from the **presenting** controller, i.e. if `VC 2` presented `UINavigationController` with `VC 1`, then:

`vc2.dismiss(animated:true, completion:nil)`

---

***Update***

Try editing the code used to dismiss the modal that you showed on a previous comment like this:

```
@IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
   self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If that doesn't work try this also:

```
@IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
   self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The problem occurs when I present VC1 from VC2, then switch to Tab 1 (VC1), then switch back to Tab 2 and dismiss already presented VC1

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way: 
first, if you want to present VC1 from VC2 and you don't intend to let the user navigate further down the data hierarchy, make your segue from VC2 point directly to VC1 rather than to the navigation controller that VC1 is linked to. You don't need to override `prepareForSegue` as you've already defined the segue to `Present modally` the destination controller.
Then in VC1 just call `dismiss(animated:)` when you want to close it. This way VC1 will forward the dismissal call to the controller that presented it.
This should do it. Have fun! :-)

EDIT: When you present VC1, it usually occupies the whole screen which prevents the user from going to Tab1 before closing VC1.

Comment: To avoid full screen presentation, I segued to NavigationVC instead of UIVC. I am over riding prepare for segue because this a detail view and I am pushing data from table to it. I don't want to present it on full screen and VC1 is also a master detail view having further detail views.

Comment: Ok, this explains a lot. Having the segue point to the navigation controller has nothing to do with full screen presentation. If you want to modify the size of a controller when presented modally, you have to set that controller's `modalPresentationStyle` property to `.custom` and provide an object that conforms to `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and a subclass of `UIPresentationController`. Check this out to see how to do it: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningCustomPresentations.html

Answer (score 0):

**Methode 1.** Use, `over full screen modal` presentation style for a view controller which is presented from VC2 to VC1 as modally by segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let DestViewController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let destinationVC = DestViewController.topViewController as! VC1

   destinationVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
}
```

Over full screen will present your view controller over your tabbar (controller) by covering it. So, end-user can't switch tabbar (unless you perform operation programatically) tabbar items. User must close this view controller to switch tabbar.

If you are using segue, to present view controller then select 'Over Full Screen' from modal presentation style in Attribute inspection

**Methode 2.** create a custom class of`UITabBarController` which extends UITabBarController as:

```
class TabBar: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        delegate = self
    }

    //MARK: UITabBarControllerDelegate Methods.
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

        //Check tab is change and VC1 is presented on VC2 or not, if presented than dismiss. 
        if let topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {

            if let childVC = ((topController.childViewControllers[1] as! UINavigationController).viewControllers)[0].presentedViewController {
                if childVC is ViewController  && self.selectedIndex == 0 {
                    childVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution, worked like a charm. I wish I could vote you up.